# Mongodb- Get distinct count of documents where a field matches a particular value

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

This is a sample document that I have:

```
{
"sessionId" : "98e9be38-3ff9-454a-aef4-625acaadbb62",
"userMessage" : "Liked It :)",
"hour" : "14"
},
{
"sessionId" : "98e9be38-3ff9-454a-aef4-625acaadbb62",
"userMessage" : "Hated It :(",
"hour" : "14"
},
{
"sessionId" : "98e9be38-3ff9-454a-aef4-625acaadbb62",
"userMessage" : "Just okay, could be better",
"hour" : "14"
}      
{
"sessionId" : "98e9be38-3ff9-454a-aef4-625acaadbb62",
"userMessage" : "Sample Message",
"hour" : "14"
},
{
"sessionId" : "98e9be38-3ff9-454a-aef4-625acaadbb62",
"userMessage" : "Sample message 2",
"hour" : "14"
}
```

I want to count the number of documents which matches userMessages to 'Liked It :)' or 'Hated It :(' or 'Just okay, could be better'.

**Expected output:**

```
{[
   "Liked It :)":5,
   "Hated It :(":3,
   "Just okay, could be better":1
]}
```

**What I have tried:**

```
db.getCollection('messagelogs').aggregate([
{"$group" : {_id:"$userMessage", count:{$sum:1}}}
])
```

But the above query groups all the 'userMessage' field which is not what I want, I want to group only the 'userMessage' fields with values 'Liked It :)', 'Hated It :(', and 'Just okay, could be better'

Comment: @Fanpark, I have updated the question, can you please have a look? The question you have marked as duplicate does not give what I want, please check and let me know

Comment: Tony Please ask a new question if you think there is ambiguity in the existing one. But for now I cannot see any difference in your question and the duplicate answer.  You just need to use one `$match` stage at the begining with the `$in` expression. Something like `{ $match: { userMessage: { $in: [ 'Liked It :)', 'Hated It :(', 'Just okay' ] }}}`